# How to use .so files as main arguments in c?

Tags: c, arguments, shared-libraries, program-entry-point

I have to write a c program, that gets a .so file (shared-object) as an argument in the main method and call a function f on it. It expects a function f to exist on this library. My program has to work for any .so file, so I can't include them directly.

so by calling

```
./myprogram myLibrary.so
```

myprogram has to do something like this:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return argv[1].f();
 }
```

How can I achieve this and what else do I have to consider when compiling my code?

Comment: `man dlopen`, `man dlsym`, etc

Comment: More specifically: `dlopen` is going to want a filename, as a string.  And the command line (`argv`) is a good way of passing strings in to a program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called "dynamic loading" of libraries.  On Unix-like operating systems, the call you're looking for is [dlopen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) .  It takes a filename and some flags, and opens the specified shared library.  You can then use the `dlsym()` routine to look up individual symbols (like your function f()), which you can then call elsewhere in your program.